# SQL Server 2005 Express cannot update datetime field when windows is set to Italian

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2005-express

I am struggling with an MS SQL 2005 Express issue. A query like the one below works perfect when Windows Regional Options (control panel) is set to English (United States), but it fails when set to Italian (and maybe other languages).

```
UPDATE MyTable SET StartDate='2009-07-14 12:05:30' WHERE ID=7
```

I tried also many different date-time formats such as ISO 8601:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
```

(see also: http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes)

None of these formats work except for yyyyMMdd, but then I loose the time which is not acceptable.

Also executing this query first makes no difference:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english
```

PS: I execute the query from a .Net program, but SQL Server Management Studio gives the same result: it cannot convert the string into a data-time. As soon as the settings are changed back to US English it works again.

How do I make this query work with other language settings?

Answer (score 2):

You should use region-independent dates. In SQL Server, you can do this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET StartDate={ts '2009-07-14 12:05:30'} WHERE ID=7
```

From code, it's even better is to use named parameters and pass a DateTime object as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss format?

```
UPDATE MyTable SET StartDate='20090714 12:05:30' WHERE ID=7
```

Comment: Sorry it did not work, but I now think it was because VB.net replaced the ":" by ".". No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of trying I found the solution. The ISO 8601 format works perfect in MS SQL, but something went wrong in formatting the date in VB.net.

First I used the following format specifier:

Dim dateString As String = aDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")

However, somehow the result is something like "2009-07-14T12.05.30" instead of "2009-07-14T12:05:30", so dots instead of ":"!

When using

Dim dateString As String = aDate.ToString("s")

The correct format is applied: "2009-07-14T12:05:30".